# Counting across subsets in dataframes the R-way

Tags: r, vectorization

In R I have a dataframe `df` of this form:

```
a b id
1 2 1234758
1 1 1234758
3 5 1234759
5 5 1234759
5 5 1234759
2 2 1234760
```

I want to count how many times I observe a change between `df$a` and `df$b` for each id value.

Since I am interested in some the numbers of ID as well I did

```
summary <- as.data.frame(table(df$id))
id n_id
2  1234758
3  1234759
1  1234760
```

then I wrote this to compute the number of times a and b changes for each id (both `df` and `summary` are sorted by `id`)

```
summary$jumps <- 0
k <- 1
for(i in 1:nrow(summary)) {
n <- summary$n_id[i]
for(j in k:k+n-1) if(df$a[j] != df$b[j]) summary$jumps[i] <- summary$jumps[i] + 1 
  k <- k + n 
}
```

which looks up each entry in `df` the number of time each id appears, checks a and b and update the appropriate entry in summary. This works as intended, but it looks slow to me.

I am fairly new to R, what would we be a more efficient way of doing this in R? How would you vectorize this code? The dataframe has about 30 million such lines.

Comment: With `base R` `aggregate(cbind(jumps = a!=b)~id, df1, FUN=sum)`

Comment: Lovely, this looks spot on. Contrary to the answer below which somehow dropped a third of my observations. I also enjoy that this needs no additional package or data.table conversion. I'd pick this if you made it to an answer.

Comment: THanks for the comments.  Posted that as a solution.

Comment: This is another proof of how bad loops in R are. My original code run in about an hour. This runs in a fistful of seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(cbind(jumps = a!=b)~id, df1, FUN=sum)
```

Comment: what if I wanted to apply a similar solution if I wanted to instead drop the whole group (i.e. all entries with a given ID) if the FIRST one (sorted by yet another parameter, date) of them contained a na?

Comment: I managed to work it out with loops, I guess I shall make a new question :)

Comment: @ThreeDiag  The reason I asked to update is I am not sure whether the NAs are in the 'date' or somewhere else

Comment: I would like to drop all rows matching a certain id, provided that the first row of observations matching said id (first by date), contains an NA in either a or b.

Comment: @ThreeDiag  In that case, try `setDT(df1)[, if(!(is.na(b[1])|is.na(a[1]))) sum(a!=b) , id]`

Comment: I see, shall give it a try in a little, any chance to do it in basic R?

Comment: @ThreeDiag  Try `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df1, df1$id), function(x) if(!(is.na(x$a[1])|is.na(x$b[1]))) data.frame(id = x$id[1], sum=sum(x$a!=x$b))))`

Comment: The DT version seemed to be dropping an excessive number of observations (maybe akin to the answer above).

The other version tanked my computer by taking some large amount of memory (I have some memory limitation on the current machine)

Comment: Mh, it might be due to an error in as.data.frame(...) at some point, I shall have a look. Thanks for the helps

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could use data.table to solve it in a fairly straight forward way;

```
library(data.table)

dt = setDT(df)                    # Create a data table
dt[,list(jumps=sum(a!=b)),by=id]  # Sum rows where a!=b grouped by id

#         id jumps
# 1: 1234758     1
# 2: 1234759     1
# 3: 1234760     0
```

Comment: There seems to be some issue. If I count the number of  rows in `summary <- dt[,list...]` I would expect them to be exactly the same as `length(unique(df$id))`, but this is not the case, it look some ID disappear in the process?

Comment: Might be because ID I have are longer than the ones I wrote in the post above? I thought it made no difference, but they are actually 14 digits long